# What do you call the sound emitted by a car horn?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the sound emitted by a car horn? Is there a formal, non-informal term for the sound? I am pretty sure there is an informal and a formal word for it, but I rather have the formal word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is [*honk*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/honk).

> 1. (transitive, intransitive) To use a car horn.
>
>    > They stood and observed how long it took for the other cars to honk.
> 2. (intransitive) To make a loud, harsh sound like a car horn